# Microsoft Teams no install event - can't send welcome message

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Up until this Friday, MS Teams would always send a conversationUpdate event payload to our bot messaging endpoint whenever a user installed our app in Teams.

This stopped happening suddenly and now we only get a message when an app is added to a Team scope and not just personal scope.

Given that: how do we know to send a Welcome message via our bot to a user that installed our app if we receive no message, no payload. Nothing hits our bot messaging endpoint.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're sure the user is actually -installing- the bot, not just connecting directly to the bot's endpoint?

Comment: @Mike we could not reproduce the issue on our side.Could you please share your manifest?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. Turns out that what used to work in the past, doesn't anymore in that uninstalling a bot from Teams and reinstalling would trigger the event but it doesn't anymore. Looking at the documentation I suppose that's the way it was supposed to work, but didn't up until now and I was wrongly relying on it.